# Plugin for tfs 2012 won't fire

Tags: visual-studio-2012, plugins, tfs

I'm writing a plugin for TFS so that I can track changes in my WITs.

```
namespace TFSServerEventHandler
{
public class WorkItemChangedEventHandler : ISubscriber
{
    public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
    {
        return new Type[1] { typeof(WorkItemChangedEvent) };
    }

    public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs,
                                                out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
    {
        statusCode = 0;
        properties = null;
        statusMessage = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is WorkItemChangedEvent)
            {
                WorkItemChangedEvent ev = notificationEventArgs as WorkItemChangedEvent;
                EventLog.WriteEntry("WorkItemChangedEventHandler", "WorkItem " + ev.WorkItemTitle + " was modified");
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test.txt", "welcome");
                Console.WriteLine("test");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return "WorkItemChangedEventHandler"; }
    }

    public SubscriberPriority Priority
    {
        get { return SubscriberPriority.Normal; }
    }
}
}
```

When I build this code and add the DLL to my TFS installation, the application is restarting. But when I change/add/delete a workitem then nothing happens.

What could this be?

kind regards

ps, I tried to write to a txt file to see if the problem was with writing to the event log

Comment: Does the event fire?  Have you tried debugging it (attach to process w3wp.exe)

Comment: No, when i add it to that process nothing happens. Also when i add a break point, it doesnt break

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct but any exception will go unnoticed.

I suspect most of the `EventLog.WriteEntry` call. It will fail unless you create the source. This is easily done running `New-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "WorkItemChangedEventHandler"` in an elevated Powershell prompt.

You can also tweak your code and use `Trace.Writeline`. The output can be viewed using [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) from Microsoft's SysInternals site.
Make sure to enable the **Capture Global Win32** option.

Do not forget to add some logging in the `catch` clause.

Comment: It didn't help. Thanks for helping, but it still doesn't run -.-

Comment: Added some suggestions. You can take a look at TFS Aggregator for a ready-to-use solution.

Comment: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Kan een of meer van de gevraagde typen niet laden. Haal de LoaderExceptions-eigenschap op voor meer informatie. bij System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) bij System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() bij System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() bij Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TypeUtils.GetAllTypes(IEnumerable`1 assemblies, Func`2 filter)

this is a error I find in the eventlog under TFS and then Debug. It's in Dutch. But I think you maybe understand the error

Comment: You screwed up something in the references and TFS cannot load your DLL. This may explain why you see no logging.